# Why would you use the Azure Media Player instead of the standard HTML5 video player?

Tags: html5-video, azure-media-services

Modern web browsers have the video tag built in, as of:

- Chrome 4.0
- IE 9.0
- FF 3.5
- Safari 4.0

Why would I use Microsoft's Azure Media Player?  Which benefits does this offer over this standard player?

Answer (score 4):

Some of the benefits include:

- Automatic platform detection and playback
- Picks the best format for a browser / device.
- Unified HTML5 and JS APIs Playback for protected content AES & Play Ready
- Video player debugging Logging, monitor
  quality of bit rate streams, diagnostic info

Scott Hanselman explains it well [in this Channel 9 video.](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Azure-Media-Services-101-Get-your-video-online-now-?ocid=player)

AES and Play Ready in particular are extremely useful for developers and copyright owners who are looking to protect their content. In the past, developers were forced to rely on tools such as **Flash** to protect their investment.

Automatic platform detection and playback is helpful as well, as the developer will not have to manually determine which stream is best for their user. [Encoding.com offers a great explanation](https://www.encoding.com/http-live-streaming-hls/) to how different platforms utlize DRM such as HLS.

> HLS (HTTP Live Streaming) is an emerging standard in adaptive bitrate video. Adaptive bitrate video delivery is a combination of server and client software that detects a client’s bandwidth capacity and adjusts the quality of the video stream between multiple bitrates and/or resolutions. The adaptive bitrate video experience is superior to delivering a static video file at a single bitrate, because the video stream can be switched midstream to be as good or bad as the client’s available network speed (as opposed to the buffering or interruption in playback that can happen when client’s network speed can’t support the quality of video).